# Uninstaller doesn't delete copied library to System Folder in VS2010 installer project.

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, uninstallation

I have a windows desktop application. I am preparing msi using microsoft visual studio 2010 installer project. For my purpose I need to copy a certain DLL into System Folder during installation. When I run my uninstaller after installation is done, it doesn't delete that library from system folder.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Here is my UnInstaller.cpp

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //WinExec("msiexec.exe /i {B49233F8-814D-432F-BE05-D6BA334A0087}", SW_SHOW);
    WinExec("msiexec.exe /i {050E4942-5DF2-4F46-B6BC-1296761DA4C1}", SW_SHOW);
}
```

Comment: How do you know for certain that your app is the only user of that DLL? The System Folder is a shared resource, and you generally can't assume that you may delete a DLL just because you installed it.

Comment: Because it will only work with my App.

Comment: If the DLL is only for your app. then why are you installing it in a shared location? Something here doesn't make sense, and I'm not surprised that MSI has similar problems understanding what it should do.

Comment: Because it is specified by KISA. Their specification forces me to do so. Anyway, do you have any idea how I can do this?

Comment: I don't even know what KISA is, sorry.

Comment: The Korean Internet and Security Agency.

Comment: That seems a rather localized problem. Also, I suspect that you may be misinterpreting that rule as it doesn't exactly help security as you describe it.

Comment: @MSalters No, I am exactly certain about the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ever marked that file's properties in the setup as Permanent or SharedLegacyFile and installed it, then it will not be uninstalled. They are not settings you cam change in the project and expect them to change on the system because the system will have marked them for not uninstalling. If you look in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDlls and the path to your file is there, for example, then you have unnecessarily marked it shared.

Comment: I haven't got what u have said. Please could you elaborate more? Where to change? I didn't find any way to change the properties for special folders such as System Folder.

Comment: I didn't say anything about the system folder, so I don't know what you mean. I'm referring to the files that you may have marked as Permanent or SharedLegacy. There is nothing I can recommend changing anyway because I'm listing probable causes and you haven't said whether you've looked at the registry location.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Installer best practices state that you should avoid installing shared resources to the windows / system folders and that when you must they should be marked as permanent.